# Match select the max value from another data frame

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames v1 and V2. I need to add column y from v2 to data frame v1 but want the matched value to be max. for example

```
v1 <- data.frame(x = c("a1","b2"))
v2 <- data.frame(x = c("a1","a1","b2","b2"), y= c(1,3,4,6))
```

I am using below line to populate y column in v1.

```
v1$y <-v2$y[match(v1$x,v2$x)]
```

which outputs below.

```
> v1
   x y
1 a1 1
2 b2 4
```

`match` is taking  y based on the first occurrence but I need it based on max. something like below

```
> v1
   x y
1 a1 3
2 b2 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first aggregate to find the max and then match it to v1.

```
tt <- aggregate(y ~ x, data=v2, FUN=max)
v1$y <-tt$y[match(v1$x,tt$x)]
v1
#   x y
#1 a1 3
#2 b2 6
```

Comment: I dint need to change my present code with this solution

Answer (score 4):

As `match` returns first match, you can `order` the data such that the first match is the `max` match

```
v2 <- v2[order(v2$x, -v2$y), ]
v1$y <- v2$y[match(v1$x, v2$x)]

v1
#   x y
#1 a1 3
#2 b2 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to aggregate first and then join (or match),

```
merge(v1, aggregate(y~x, v2, max), by = 'x')
```

or

```
max_v2 <- aggregate(y~x, v2, max)
max_v2$y[match(v1$x, max_v2$x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible `base` solution:

```
new_df<-merge(v1,v2, by="x")
aggregate(.~x, new_df,max)
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
v1 %>% 
   left_join(v2, "x") %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   summarise(y=max(y))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x         y
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a1        3
2 b2        6
```

Or another `base` option:

```
 aggregate(.~x,v2[v1$x %in% v2$x,],max)
   x y
1 a1 3
2 b2 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
v1 <- data.table(x = c("a1","b2"))
v2 <- data.table(x = c("a1","a1","b2","b2"), y= c(1,3,4,6))

v2[, .(y=max(y)), x][v1, on="x"]
# > v2[, .(y=max(y)), x][v1, on="x"]
#     x y
# 1: a1 3
# 2: b2 6
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter v2 for for max values and then match

```
library(dplyr)

v1 <- data.frame(x = c("a1","b2"))
v2 <- data.frame(x = c("a1","a1","b2","b2"), y= c(1,3,4,6))

v2.sub <- v2 %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(y==max(y))

v1$y <-v2.sub$y[match(v1$x,v2.sub$x)]
```